# SQL - beginner. Select average number of views per post in data.SE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I know nothing about SQL but after watching a few posts I gave it a try. Here is my first (failing) query.

On [data.stackexchange.com/biology](https://data.stackexchange.com/biology/query/), I am trying to query the average number of views a post get per tag (and I would like them sorted). I tried

```
SELECT Tags, AVG(ViewCount) AS avgNbViewsPerPost from Posts GROUP BY Tags
ORDER BY avgNbViewsPerPost
```

but the results contain only integers (surprising for an average) and seem to be displaying sometimes the maximum number of views per tag, sometimes just some other random number. Can you help me out?

Comment: On the information available, the query is fine

Comment: Averaging an integer will return an integer. You could do `AVG(1.0 * ViewCount)` to return a decimal.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Microsoft SQL-Server? Don't use tags for a database you're not using.

Comment: @ZLK I have a table containing the integers from 1 to 10. When I do `SELECT AVG(n) FROM numbers` I get `5.5`.

Comment: @Barmar I'm guessing that's in MySQL? If so, then I guess it works differently to SQL Server. See return types here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177677.aspx

Comment: @ZLK I've removed the mysql tag, since his question is related to SEDE, which uses T-SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Try below if it helps :

```
SELECT Tags, AVG(cast(ViewCount as decimal)) AS avgNbViewsPerPost from Posts GROUP BY Tags
```

ORDER BY avgNbViewsPerPost

Answer (score 0):

Try implicit converting:

```
SELECT Tags, AVG(1. * ViewCount) AS avgNbViewsPerPost 
FROM Posts 
GROUP BY Tags 
ORDER BY avgNbViewsPerPost
```

Or try explicit converting via cast or convert. Output of `AVG` function is the same data type as input.